# не отправляет данные из формы

Tags: php, javascript, html

на странице есть каталог и поиск, можно добавить товар в корзину, в каталоге всё работает, но через поиск выдаёт ошибку:
"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

вывод каталога:

```
var html = '<h2>Каталог </h2>';
html+='<table cellpadding="7" border="2">';
html+='<tr>';
            html+='<td><a>Товар</a></td>';
            html+='<td><a>Цена</a></td>';
            html+='</tr>';
for(i=0;i<product.length;i++){
html+='<tr>';
html+='<td>'+product[i]+'</td>';
html+='<td>'+cost[i]+'</td>';
html+='<td><form action="http://localhost:81/bd/php/basket.php" method="post" name="form_s">';
html+='<input style="vertical-align: top;"  name="submit_s" type="submit" value="Добавить в корзину">';
html+='<input  name="text" type="hidden" type="text" value=';
html+= i ;
html+='>';
html+='</form></td>';
html+='</tr>';

}

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML= html ;
```

Поиск:

```
   function searh()
{var html = '<h2>Результат поиска </h2>'
    html+='<table cellpadding="7" border="2">';
    html+='<tr>';
            html+='<td><a>Товар</a></td>';
            html+='<td><a>Цена</a></td>';
            html+='</tr>';
var prod= document.forms["search"].elements["product"].value;
for(var i=0; i<product.length; i++){
    if(product[i]==prod){
            document.getElementById('container').onclick = function() {
            this.innerHTML = '';
 }
            html+='<tr>';
html+='<td>'+product[i]+'</td>';
html+='<td>'+cost[i]+'</td>';
html+='<td><form action="http://localhost:81/bd/php/basket.php" method="post" name="form_s">';
html+='<input style="vertical-align: top;"  name="submit_s" type="submit" value="Добавить в корзину">';
html+='<input  name="text" type="hidden" type="text" value=';
html+= i ;
html+='>';
html+='</form></td>';
html+='</tr>';

    }

};

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML= html ;      


}
```

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, то что бы получить данные с формы, чаще всего (думаю, что всегда) используют php  и с него метод `$_POST["название переменной"];`. А там уже и сможете записать в базу если нужно ну и куча остальных действий. Так же убедитесь, что в форме указано action="тут должен быть скрипт php" и method="Тут либо POST либо GET". Прим. В вашем случае POST.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй заменить
action="http://localhost:81/bd/php/basket.php"
на
action="' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'bd/php/basket.php'"